# C# - Get value of xml element with its attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get the value of an element using a XML attribute criteria. Essentially I just want one value from the entire document and I've been trying to query it directly. This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list version="1.0">
   <meta>
      <type>resource-list</type>
   </meta>
   <resources start="0" count="1">
      <resource classname="Quote">
         <field name="name">Microsoft Corporation</field> <!-- I want this!!! -->
         <field name="price">49.869999</field>
         <field name="symbol">MSFT</field>
         <field name="ts">1461960000</field>
         <field name="type">equity</field>
         <field name="utctime">2016-04-29T20:00:00+0000</field>
         <field name="volume">48411684</field>
      </resource>
   </resources>
</list>
```

In particular, I want the field with the "name" attribute in it. This is what I've done to retrieve this:

```
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(httpResponseBody);
            string name = (string)xDoc.Elements("field").First(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "name");
```

I get an "element not matching sequence" error. When I try to experiment with this or change anything, I get an object not set to reference error.

I sense that I've made a simple parsing mistake here, but any help would be appreciated (as well as where I've gone wrong and what I can do to prevent this in the future!)

Thank-you!

Comment: `string name = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//field[@name='name']").InnerText`

Comment: Use `Descendants("field")` instead of `Elements("field")`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen using LINQ is preferred, but if you must use XPath you need `xDoc.XPathSelectElement(...)`.  There is no `SelectSingleNode` method on `XDocument`.

Comment: @CharlesMager nice catch, was thinking about `XmlDocument`

Comment: Try this instead :  var results = xDoc.Descendants("field").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "name").FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Elements` query only finds *immediate children* of the current node.  i.e. `Elements` will only return the root `list` element.

This either means you need to query like:

```
doc.Elements("list").Elements("resources").Elements(...
```

Or you can use `Descendants`, which will many any *descendant* of the current node, so:

```
var name = (string)doc.Descendants("field")
    .First(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "name");
```

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation, works perfectly now :).

Comment: Clean and nice. Thank you!